# More Tab, Row Image Tint (Xcode 9 + Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

so I'm using the native "more" function for tab bars in Xcode. I've managed to style the navigation bar & title color programmatically.

```
//sets the font color
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white]

//sets the tint color, which dictates the button color
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white

//sets the Bar tint color
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 175/255, blue: 65/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

But is there a way to change the tint on these blue icons (reference images below)? The images I'm uploading are green, but it's being tinted & I can't find the setting. Does anyone know how to change this?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdM4E.png), [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wje2b.png)

Comment: do you want to change the color of TabBar or NavigationBar?

Comment: @saroshmirza I want to change the tint of the blue images/icons on the left of the cells in the table view & within the "edit" function. Check the image links at the bottom of the post for reference :)

Comment: @JamesRhymer the blue colour displayed items is image or button?

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ They are just the images assigned to the view controllers on the tab bar. The blue is only showing once you click "more" to view all of the other connected view controllers. They are all colored correctly on the tab bar, but when I click "more" the images are still blue.

Comment: have you give tint colour to images ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to initialize the image:

`UIImage.(withRenderingMode: .alwaysTemplate)`

and then change

`UIImageView.tintColor = .green`

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure how to initialize the images in this case if I have no way to  connect to it? The more section doesn't have a view controller or any way for me to reference them by name. Just making sure did you see the attached images?

Comment: Could you just share the cellForRow method.